# push gateway cannot connect to local host

Tags: python, prometheus

I am trying to test some prometheus metrics, by pushing to a local pushgateway. The pushgateway docker image is running and I can see it in my browser when I use:
    http://localhost:9091/metrics

However, when I run the python script to push the metrics, I get a 404 error.

```
push_to_gateway('localhost:9091', job=job_name, registry=registry)
```

Error: 
    urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Is there something I'm missing in the push address? I have tried adding /metrics but that has the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy needs to be unset where you are pushing to local host.